# Identifying special characters in password verification in python

Tags: python, validation, input, passwords

I am working on an assignment for password validation where the program keeps asking the user for a valid password until one is given. I am having trouble checking the input string for special characters. Currently the program accepts the password even if their is no special characters. Also I would like to implement a feature that terminates the loop after 3 unsuccessful attempts but am not sure which loop to implement the count in.
Here is my code:

```
import re

specialCharacters = ['$', '#', '@', '!', '*']

def passwordValidation():
    while True:
         password = input("Please enter a password: ")
        if len(password) < 6:
            print("Your password must be at least 6 characters.")
        elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
            print("Your password must have at least 1 number")
        elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None:
            print("Your password must have at least 1 uppercase letter.")
        elif re.search('specialCharacters',password) is None:
            print("Your password must have at least 1 special character ($, #, @, !, *)")
        else:
            print("Congratulations! Your password is valid.")
            break
passwordValidation()
```

Comment: Your code checks whether the password contains the word "specialCharacters". First, remove the quotes around it. Second, convert the value of the variable to a regular expression: `specialCharacters = r"[\$#@!\*]"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use regular expression for something so simple.  How about:

```
elif not any(c in specialCharacters for c in password):
```

or

```
specialCharacters = set('$#@!*')
...
elif not specialCharacters.intersection(password):
```